# Windows 7 Beta and Invalid MCI device ID. Use

Tags: delphi, windows-7

Not certain if this will get much response due to the newness of Windows 7 and its beta release, but here goes...

Some caveats;

1). I have not torn into my code yet

2). The app works great in Vista and below

3). Uses MMSystem for multimedai playing of mp3 and cds.

I have an application that plays music CDs (cda) and mp3s that works great in Windows Vista and below, XP, 2000 etc.

When run on Windows 7 Beta, I get... Invalid MCI device ID. Use the ID returned when operating the MCI device when initializing the player.

Is this part of a bug in Windows 7 Beta and its media player or the main focus of my question, does/has anyone else experienced this and found a simple solution before I tear into my code?

Thanks!

JOhn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without knowing more about your exact project, I am going to say, YES, there is a bug with Windows 7's Media player.

Microsoft recomends you install this patch as soon as you finish installing Windows 7 Beta 1.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/961367